# Class of people that contain vs contains

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Can you please help with which one is correct?

1. That class of people **contains** unrelated members.
2. That class of people **contain** unrelated members.

My grammar software assigned both as correct. I would think class be assigned as singular and hence should be 1.

Comment: The important point is that it's always the head noun of the noun phrase that determines the verb form. Since singular "class" is the head, it follows that the verb should be the singular form "contains". The _of_ phrase simply adds info about the head, so "people" cannot possibly be the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is correct. It is the class (a singular noun) that contains unrelated members.
It can't be "people" that contain unrelated members, because the unrelated members are other people, and people can't contain people.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the verb links to the word "class" so it is:

- The class of people contains members...

But if we start describing the people then:

- The class of people who contain knowledge contains members...

Here "people who contain" and "class that contains".